# ActionabrSherlock and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I don't get my fragment to work... :-(

My Activity:

```
public class Test extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.title);
//      actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);



    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(dayName(Calendar.MONDAY))
            .setTabListener(new WeekDayTabListener(getApplicationContext()));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    ...

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(dayName(Calendar.SUNDAY))
            .setTabListener(new WeekDayTabListener(getApplicationContext()));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}



public static class WeekDayTabListener implements TabListener {

    private Context context;

    public WeekDayTabListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Tools.longToast(tab.getText().toString(), this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

my xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/weekDayFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.test.fragment.DayFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally my Fragment:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DayFragment extends SherlockFragment { 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(c);
        TextView tv = new TextView(c);
        tv.setText("foo");
        l.addView(tv);

        return l;
    }
}
```

If I execute, I get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.fragment/com.test.fragment.Test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

So if i comment out the  parte there is no error - but the path is correct, so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set the the Theme to either Theme.Sherlock or one of its child themes (e.g. Theme.Sherlock.Light)?

Comment: Yes, the theme is Sherlock.Light or do I also have to decalre the Fragment in my Manifest?

Comment: No you do not, might be worht telling us what version of ABS you are on as there differences from 3 to 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class Test needs to extend `SherlockFragmentActivity` not `SherlockActivity`:

```
class Test extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your fragments `onCreateView()` method you need to inflate a layout.

For example

```
.....
myInflater = inflater;
TextView tv;
tv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout_here);
.....
```

From here you can then add your linear layout to your view.

Please not that this is only pseudo code and you will have to play around with the syntax to get it working.

Comment: He creates a view in code that works just as good as inflation, inflation is the process of creating object from xml.

Comment: I first tried inflating and then changed to create in code to be shure not to make mistakes while inflating.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:name="com.test.fragment.DayFragment"` instead of `class="com.test.fragment.DayFragment"`in your xml.

Answer (score -1):

Aaah...

After wasting **three hours** trying to change my (package)names to whatever, inflating different views reading beginner tutorials over and over the solution was soooo simple:

Removing **android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"** did the job...